# How to fix scrollbars troubles in Python Tkinter/Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

How to fix scrollbars troubles in Python Tkinter/Canvas?

I have added scrollbars to my app using Canvas and got some troubles. I can [scroll window](https://youtu.be/Ok3wIAZa8ko) content when vertical scrollbar is disabled. Horizontal scroolbar works normal.

Btw, I've got another problem. A mysterious grey frame appears when I switch between frames or when I click on fields to input something. [Here you can see that frame above the tabs and near the scrollbars.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05dKJ.png) Is there a way to fix it in some way?

Here is my code:

```
class Window(Tk):
    is_reset = True

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("720x500+760+200")
        self.resizable(True, True)
        self.title("Калькулятор СМО")

        self.scrollbar_x = Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.scrollbar_y = Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.scrollbar_x.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.scrollbar_y.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_x.set, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_y.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.scrollbar_x.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.scrollbar_y.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.content_frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.content_frame, anchor=tk.NW)

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.content_frame)
        self.notebook.grid()

        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.frame3 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.frame4 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.frame5 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.frame1.grid()
        self.frame2.grid()
        self.frame3.grid()
        self.frame4.grid()
        self.frame5.grid()
        self.notebook.add(self.frame1, text="Одноканальна СМО з відмовами")
        self.notebook.add(self.frame2, text="Багатоканальна СМО з відмовами")
        self.notebook.add(self.frame3, text="Одноканальна СМО з очікуванням з обмеженою чергою")
        self.notebook.add(self.frame4, text="Багатоканальна СМО з очікуванням з необмеженою чергою")
        self.notebook.add(self.frame5, text="Багатоканальна СМО з обмеженою чергою")
        self.content_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units"))
```

Comment: You didn't add any widgets on `notebook`. That why we can't do anything on vertical.